# Make Button Follow Mouse Cursor

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a button follow the cursor, but my code only seems to just go to the mouse cursor right after execution and just stay there. Can anyone give me the correct code and help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Location = Cursor.Position;
            
              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That `button1.Location = Cursor.Position;` does *not* set up a "relation" between both locations, but copies it *once* at the moment that that line is executed (which is on form load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest overriding the `OnMouseMove` method of the `MainForm` and using the `Location` property of the `MouseEventArgs e` argument. This will provide the correct `Client` coordinates of the cursor taking into account where `MainForm` is located on the screen. Then you can offset that value using the `Width` and `Height` properties of `buttonMoveMe` to center it on the mouse.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        var point = new Point(
            e.Location.X - (buttonMoveMe.Width / 2), 
            e.Location.Y - (buttonMoveMe.Height / 2));
        buttonMoveMe.Location = point;
    }
}
```

Be aware that this event _will not be received when the mouse is *over the button itself*. The button will be getting the `MouseMove` events (not the MainForm) in this case. In other words, this basic suggestion only moves the button when the mouse *leaves* the button.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/button_follows_cursor.git) this sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `MouseMove` event.
So these are things you need to do:

1. Create a button control which is going to follow the cursor. (I will call it `yourButton`)
2. Open event menu of the control (click on it in the constructor).
3. Find event `MouseMove` inside `Mouse` category.
4. Double click on it. (This will automatically create the method which will be linked to the event)
5. In this method write: `yourButton.Location = e.Location;`

So it should look like that:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    yourButton.Location = e.Location;
}
```

In my example I made button follow my cursor inside the form.

If you need shorter way, you can just copy-paste the method I wrote before and in the form class constructor add:

```
this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
```

In this way your code would look like that:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    yourButton.Location = e.Location;
}
```

Hope this will help you, have a nice day!

**UPD:**

In case you want the cursor to be in the center of the button, you should edit our previous `Form1_MouseMove` and add one more event.

1. Edit the code of `Form1_MouseMove`, now it should be:

   `yourButton.Location = new Point(e.X - yourButton.Width / 2, e.Y - yourButton.Height / 2);`
2. Now you need to use MouseMove method of the button (Follow the previous steps, but for button (Click on it -> Events -> Mouse category -> double click on MouseMove))
3. In newly created method write:

   `yourButton.Location = new Point(e.X + yourButton.Left - yourButton.Width / 2, e.Y + yourButton.Top - yourButton.Height / 2);`

Hope this helped now)

Comment: I like the fact that it is simple, but it's kind of in the left of the cursor, I want it to be right in front of it. (in the middle.)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit, you didn't mention that in the question, but it's okay

Answer (score -1):

Your `Form1_Load` method is only executed, as its name says, when the form is loaded.

You want to execute your code every time the mouse move, si you can do it like this (not tested):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Location = Cursor.Position;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load' and no accessible extension method 'Form1_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
What do i do now?

Comment: Intellisense helped me fix the previous error, but upon on execution i get a "System.ArgumentException: 'Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.'"

Comment: @ingham plz consider taking into account that `Cursor.Position` is in `Screen` coordinates whereas `button.Location` is `Client` coordinates relative to `Form1`. Try this: Make the `Form1.StartPosition`=`FormStartPosition.CenterScreen` and put these Debug statements in your event handler: `Debug.WriteLine($"Cursor position in screen coordinates: {Cursor.Position}"); Debug.WriteLine($"Cursor position in client coordinates: {e.Location}");` I believe you'll see output similar to **Cursor position in screen coordinates: {X=1543,Y=893}
Cursor position in client coordinates: {X=23,Y=51}**

Comment: @ingham I explained the downvote and will be glad to remove it if you correct the fact that you are assigning the Cursor.Position (which is in screen coordinates) to the button1.Location (which is in Client coordinates). It's just a mismatch that makes the answer technically incorrect, but I promise you it's not malicious and like I said I will reverse the downvote is that is corrected.