# Button Not In The Center Of The Cursor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have typed like 2 questions based on 1 thing, Making a button follow the cursor, But anyways, Is it possible to make the button right in the center of the cursor instead of being
in the corner left of the cursor?  If yes, then can you show me the code?
[What i don't want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbdPa.png)
[What i want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SByrc.png)

And here is all the code.
Form1.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Location = Cursor.Position;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Location property represent the upper left corner of the control. If you want to center the mouse position you should calculate the correct location of the button considering its size and height divided by two and set the X and Y properties of the Location property

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776471/5438626) answer your question?